# Unable to get generic OAuth2 client working with CAS server using pac4j

Tags: json, oauth-2.0, instagram-api, cas, apereo

I am working on integrating Login with Instagram using delegated authentication in CAS server. I have configured all the requisite properties in cas.properties file and also created a service registration JSON file for it. When I login into Instagram account I am redirected back to CAS login page and nothing happens.

I tried experimenting with the service registry JSON file as well as different properties in cas.properties

cas.properties file contains the following

```
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].id={client_id}
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].secret={client_secret}
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].authUrl=https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&client_name=instagram
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].tokenUrl=https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&client_name=instagram
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].profileUrl=https://api.instagram.com/v1
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].clientName=instagram
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].profileVerb=GET
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].profilePath=/users/self/

cas.serviceRegistry.watcherEnabled=true
cas.serviceRegistry.schedule.repeatInterval=10000
cas.serviceRegistry.schedule.startDelay=15000

cas.serviceRegistry.initFromJson=true

cas.serviceRegistry.json.location=file:/etc/cas/services/
```

The service JSON file is as follows:

```
{
  "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^https://.*.{domain}.com.*",
  "name" : "eyerne",
  "id" : 10002,
  "description" : "This service definition authorizes the eyerne URL.",
  "accessStrategy" : {
    "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy",
    "enabled" : true,
    "ssoEnabled" : true
  },
  "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
  "generateRefreshToken": true,
  "proxyPolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexMatchingRegisteredServiceProxyPolicy",
    "pattern" : "^https?://.*"
  },
  "supportedGrantTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "authorization_code", "client_credential"] ],
  "supportedResponseTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "code", "token" ] ],
  "attributeReleasePolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy"
  }
}
```

I am not able to reach the point where CAS is able to get the access token and fetch the user details using the profile URL.

Instead, I get the following errors:

```
DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuth20AuthenticationServiceSelectionStrategy] - <Authentication request is not identified as an OAuth request>

=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: [event=success,timestamp=Mon Aug 05 16:27:34 IST 2019,source=RankedAuthenticationProviderWebflowEventResolver]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_EVENT_TRIGGERED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Mon Aug 05 16:27:34 IST 2019
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================
```

If I attempt to try again and login into CAS using Instagram then I get a different error:

```
CAS is unable to process this request: "500:Internal Server Error"

org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.apereo.cas.web.flow.DelegatedClientAuthenticationAction@33ec9d9 in state 'clientAction' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
```

What do I need to do more or change in order to be able to successfully login user into CAS server using Instagram?

### Update 08/16/2019

I was able to get PAC4J to work for Instagram by patching one of its module. I had to manually add access token to the final profile url being called as well as change the authentication method from basicAuth to requestBody.

However, now when Instagram redirects me back to CAS server, after signing in, I should be redirected to the service URL. Instead I am getting redirected to the CAS login success page with the following message:

> You, tridhya123, have successfully logged into the Central
>   Authentication Service. However, you are seeing this page because CAS
>   does not know about your target destination and how to get you there.
>   Examine the authentication request again and make sure a target
>   service/application that is authorized and registered with CAS is
>   specified.

Below is the debug log file showing the login flow from Instagram to CAS:

https://file.io/ztteR3

Comment: You want to in the login page, click a button, go to `Instagram` then go back and login success, i.e.g [Deletege Authentication](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/integration/Delegate-Authentication.html) , correct? Or do you want to use `OAuth` login flow? [OAuth](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html). You are now applying both by using both `Service` and `cas.properties`, not sure what you really want.

Comment: @NgSekLong - I got your point. I am talking about Delegated Authentication using Generic OAuth2.0.

Comment: @NgSekLong - However, I was able to fix the issue partially. I had to modify pac4j as had to change the authentication method from basicAuth to requestBody and also the access token paramter was not getting appended while calling the profile URL. Now the issue i am facing is that after logging in the i am taken to the login success page in CAS instead of getting redirected to the service URL with the Service Ticket

Comment: Just asking to be sure, did you specified the `service` parameter? e.g. `https://www.mycas.com/cas/login?service=https://www.placetogo.com`

Comment: Yes, I did specify in the same way. If you see the network monitor report the /clientredirect url does not contain the service url. https://ibb.co/NFX0dgD . This url is used 2 times during the entire process automactially. I am not sure if this is the reason or not.

Comment: Since you only need Oauth as delegates authentication, your service should not use `org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService`, instead, please use something like the one I'm here https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Configuring-Service-Access-Strategy.html#disable-service-access, but make the enabled = true, and   "serviceId" : "https://www.your-target.com/.*",

Comment: yes, i have changed the service class to the Regex one you mentioned in the link and service id also accordingly. the issue now is that aftr successful login i am not taken to the service url but instead to the cas login success page. m stuck in this since more than a week.

Comment: Any way you can show your updated code, also can you give us your debug log? It is hard to debug your problem if we don't have access to your code or your log.

Comment: Hi @NgSekLong - I have modified my question above with the latest code as well as a link to the log file. Thnx.